# Is there a way to use facet_grid / facet_wrap in combination with geom_quantile in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

As the title says. I've figured out a sub-optimal work around which goes as follows:

```
data("mtcars")

tau <- c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)
cuts <- sapply(tau, function(x) quantile(mtcars[,'mpg'], x, na.rm = T))

quantiles <- sapply(mtcars[,'mpg'], function(x) {
  quant <- NA
  if(x < cuts[1]) quant <- 0
  for(i in 1:(length(cuts)-1)) {
    if(x >= cuts[i] & x < cuts[i+1]) {
      quant <- i
    } else if (x >= cuts[i+1]){
      quant <- i+1
    }
  }
  quant
})

labs <- paste0(tau[1:(length(tau)-1)], '-', tau[1:(length(tau)-1)+1])
labs <- c(paste("<", tau[1]), labs, paste(">=", tau[length(tau)]))
quantiles <- factor(quantiles, labels=labs)
mtcars$quantile <- quantiles

ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=disp, y=mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method='lm') +
  facet_wrap(quantiles, nrow = 1)
```

[image: Wrapping each quantile into it's own plot]

But what I really want to do is use ggplot's geom_quantile function like so but have it faceted. In the following output I've figured out how to factor by colour, but I can't do the same with facet_wrap which is what I'm hoping to do:

```
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=disp, y=mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_quantile(aes(colour = as.factor(..quantile..)), quantiles=tau)
```

[image: You can see I've added colour to the quantiles but I'd like them to be facetted]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't follow what your expected output is. _"but have it wrapped"_: what do you mean by this?

Comment: Running `ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=disp, y=mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_quantile(aes(colour = as.factor(..quantile..)), quantiles=tau) +
  facet_wrap(quantiles, nrow = 1)` works fine but I'm not sure that makes sense to do.

Comment: Perhaps you want `geom_quantile(aes(colour = as.factor(..quantile..)), quantiles=0.5)  +`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. @CCurtis and Jon Spring, I don't want different colours in the final output. I want it just faceted.

Comment: @Axeman, I think faceted is the better word. I want it to be on different panels as facet_wrap does. I've edited the question to make it clearer (on both fronts).

Comment: So presumably you have tried adding `+ facet_wrap(quantiles, nrow = 1)` but the output was not what you wanted. Can you explain that more? You have made a variable `quantiles` that is quantiles by `mpg`, and you are using `geom_quantile` to plot the `mpg`:`disp` relationship at three conditional quantiles. If you facet by your four `quantile` values and plot three conditional quantiles in those, you'll get 12 lines. Is that what you want?

Comment: The quantiles object is from my work around which doesn't estimate the quantile regression the same way geom_quantiles does. I'm hoping to get the quantiles from the regression output not by finding quantiles myself. Hope that explains well enough.

Comment: I still don't understand. Perhaps you can specify what you think each facet should be showing.

Comment: @Axeman each facet should be showing approximately what I put in the first image, my workaround. But I want to do it using geom_quantile.